# How to customize STPPaymentCardTextField.Representable

Tags: ios, swiftui, stripe-payments

I have successfully created the payment card text field using:

```
STPPaymentCardTextField.Representable(paymentMethodParams: $paymentMethodParams)
```

However, I'd like to remove the border.

Adding a border using the following just seems to add another border over the default one.

```
STPPaymentCardTextField.Representable(paymentMethodParams: $paymentMethodParams)
    .border(Color.red, width: 1)
```

I've also tried changing the width to 0 but the border doesn't go away.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: The `Representable` View is provided by `Stripe`, it's basically a `SwiftUI Version of `STPPaymentCardTextField`,  so you can create your own version and use it/ customize it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can just reuse the `SwiftUI` code provided by `Stripe` and add/remove your own color/customizations. The following will produce a `STPPaymentCardTextField` without a `border` color.
All we have to do, is to add `paymentCardField.borderColor = nil` in `makeUIView(context:)` method.

```
/// A SwiftUI representation of an STPPaymentCardTextField.
public struct RepresentableField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var paymentMethodParams: STPPaymentMethodParams?

    /// Initialize a SwiftUI representation of an STPPaymentCardTextField.
    /// - Parameter paymentMethodParams: A binding to the payment card text field's contents.
    /// The STPPaymentMethodParams will be `nil` if the payment card text field's contents are invalid.
    public init(paymentMethodParams: Binding<STPPaymentMethodParams?>) {
        _paymentMethodParams = paymentMethodParams
    }

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> STPPaymentCardTextField {
        let paymentCardField = STPPaymentCardTextField()
        paymentCardField.borderColor = nil //  set this to nil if you don't want a border color
        if let cardParams = paymentMethodParams?.card {
            paymentCardField.cardParams = cardParams
        }
        if let postalCode = paymentMethodParams?.billingDetails?.address?.postalCode {
            paymentCardField.postalCode = postalCode
        }
        if let countryCode = paymentMethodParams?.billingDetails?.address?.country {
            paymentCardField.countryCode = countryCode
        }
        paymentCardField.delegate = context.coordinator
        paymentCardField.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)

        return paymentCardField
    }

    public func updateUIView(_ paymentCardField: STPPaymentCardTextField, context: Context) {
        if let cardParams = paymentMethodParams?.card {
            paymentCardField.cardParams = cardParams
        }
        if let postalCode = paymentMethodParams?.billingDetails?.address?.postalCode {
            paymentCardField.postalCode = postalCode
        }
        if let countryCode = paymentMethodParams?.billingDetails?.address?.country {
            paymentCardField.countryCode = countryCode
        }
    }

    public class Coordinator: NSObject, STPPaymentCardTextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: RepresentableField
        init(parent: RepresentableField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        public func paymentCardTextFieldDidChange(_ cardField: STPPaymentCardTextField) {
            let paymentMethodParams = STPPaymentMethodParams(
                card: cardField.cardParams, billingDetails: nil, metadata: nil)
            if !cardField.isValid {
                parent.paymentMethodParams = nil
                return
            }
            if let postalCode = cardField.postalCode, let countryCode = cardField.countryCode {
                let billingDetails = STPPaymentMethodBillingDetails()
                let address = STPPaymentMethodAddress()
                address.postalCode = postalCode
                address.country = countryCode
                billingDetails.address = address
                paymentMethodParams.billingDetails = billingDetails
            }
            parent.paymentMethodParams = paymentMethodParams
        }
    }
}
```